# C++ access class method by pointer in class-templated function

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, function-pointers

I have some objects of diffirent classes with `update`, `render` and `eventHandler` methods that have same prototype for each class:

```
class Menu {
...
public:
    Menu ();

    void update (WindowState *winState);
    void render ();
    void eventHandler (SDL_Event *event);
};

class Game {
...
public:
    Game (Config *config);

    void update (WindowState *winState);
    void render ();
    void eventHandler (SDL_Event *event);
};
```

So, I want to "set active object" and call these methods by pointers:

```
struct {
    void (*update) (WindowState *winState);
    void (*render) ();
    void (*eventHandler) (SDL_Event *event);
} routines;

template<class T>
void switchRoutines (T *obj) {
    routines.update = &(obj->update);
    routines.render = &(obj->render);
    routines.eventHandler = &(obj->eventHandler);
}
...
switchRoutines<Game> (&game);
...
routines.render ();
```

However, I get type mismatch:

```
error: cannot convert 'void (Game::*)(WindowState*)' to 'void (*)(WindowState*)' in assignment
    routines.update = &(obj->update);
```

I've read that pointers to class members should be explicitly declared with their class, but my goal is to write a universal, class-independent routine switcher.

Is there a way to do it **without** using STL or Boost?

Comment: Inheritance and virtual methods?

Comment: Or if the classes don't fit in an inheritance structure, templates

Comment: Unfortunately you are denying to use the standard library. It would be easy to do with `std::function` instead of a raw function pointer.

Comment: Repeat after me (multiple times): A pointer to a non-member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function. The big difference is that a member function needs an object to be called on, while non-member function does not have that.

Comment: And the standard library is there to *help* you. Don't dismiss it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++. Class method pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319380/c-class-method-pointers)

Comment: Even if you *could* switch the routines like that. You need an **object** to call a member. You don't account for it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using type erasure and template functions, but you **must** keep also a reference to the instance on which you want to invoke the member functions.
Here is a minimal, working example:

```
struct SDL_Event;
struct WindowState;

struct Menu {
    void update (WindowState *) {}
    void render () {}
    void eventHandler (SDL_Event *) {}
};

struct Game {
    void update (WindowState *) {}
    void render () {}
    void eventHandler (SDL_Event *) {}
};

template<typename T, void(T::*)(WindowState *)>
void update(void *ptr, WindowState *winState) {
    static_cast<T *>(ptr)->update(winState);
}

template<typename T, void(T::*)()>
void render(void *ptr) {
    static_cast<T *>(ptr)->render();
}

template<typename T, void(T::*)(SDL_Event *)>
void eventHandler(void *ptr, SDL_Event *event) {
    static_cast<T *>(ptr)->eventHandler(event);
}

struct {
    void (*update) (void *, WindowState *);
    void (*render) (void *);
    void (*eventHandler) (void *, SDL_Event *);
    void *instance;
} routines;

template<class T>
void switchRoutines (T *obj) {
    routines.update = &update<T, &T::update>;
    routines.render = &render<T, &T::render>;
    routines.eventHandler = &eventHandler<T, &T::eventHandler>;
    routines.instance = obj;
}

int main() {
    Game game;
    switchRoutines<Game> (&game);
    routines.render (routines.instance);
}
```

Your expectations are quite there, but for the fact that I added an instance `void *` pointer to make it work:

```
switchRoutines<Game> (&game);
routines.render (routines.instance);
```

If you can add it to your `routines` object, well, here it is a working solution for you.